# How can I get my python game results into the html output div?

Tags: python, html, web

I'm using Pyodide for this, and need to get my div to recognize the game results in real time or as the game progresses. I think I'm just missing something in my try-catch but
I don't think I need to redefine the const. I've tried to make output a global variable, but that doesn't work either. Does anyone have any insight here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.1/full/pyodide.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<p>
      Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors.
    </p>

    <button onclick="evaluatePython()">Play!</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>Output:</div>
    <textarea id="output" style="width: 100%;" rows="10" disabled></textarea>

    <script>
      const output = document.getElementById("output");

      function addToOutput(s) {
        output.value += ">>>" + "\n" + s + "\n";
      }

      output.value = "Initializing...\n";
      // init Pyodide
      async function main() {
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide({
          indexURL: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.18.1/full/",
        });

        output.value += "Ready!\n";
        return pyodide;
      }
      let pyodideReadyPromise = main();

      async function evaluatePython() {
       let pyodide = await pyodideReadyPromise;

       try{
         let output = await pyodide.runPython(`from random import randint

t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = t[randint(0,2)]

player = False

while player == False:
    player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
    if player == computer:
          print("Tie!")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose!, computer, covers, player")
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
    elif player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You lose...", computer, "smashes", player)
        else:
            print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")
    player = False
    computer = t[randint(0,2)]`);

                  addToOutPut(output);
                  } catch (err) {
                    addToOutput(err);
                }
              }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for taking a look!